# unable to close modal after submitting in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to do an update of a form and all is working fine but the modal does not close properly when the update is done. I mean the modal did disappear, but the screen is still dark like the modal is still there and I can't click on anything else. How do I get the page to refresh and the modal to close properly ?

My code is as shown:

```
 $scope.updateStudentParticulars = function(item) {
            var currentDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy'); //for lastchangepassword field
            $scope.EditStudentForm = false;

            //alert(item.User_Key + " USER KEY")

            const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

            //zoom in to users table
            const ref = rootRef.child('Users');

            ref.child(item.User_Key).update({
                name: item.Student_Name,
                email: item.Student_Email,
                role: "student",
                accountStatus: "Activated",
                yearJoined: item.Year_Joined,
                password: item.Password,
                passwordChangedDate: currentDate,
                gpa: 0.00,
                profile: {
                    address: item.Address,
                    citizenship: item.Citizenship,
                    gender: item.Gender,
                    nok: item.Nok,
                    nokPhone: item.Nok_Phone,
                    phone: item.Phone
                }

            });
            alert("Update Successful !")
            $route.reload();

        }
```

The modal code is declared in a html file:

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Student Particulars</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div ng-include src="'templates/editStudentForm.html'"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But ... where is your modal code ?

Comment: its in another html file, i have edited the question and added in the code

Comment: That's nice, but now, where is you JS modal code ?

Comment: I called a $scope.EditStudentForm = 'true' when initializing the js, and in the updateFunction as seen above, I set it to 'false' in the function.

Comment: I mean, I need something to work on, here you don't give your framework, you don't give your JS code, you don't give your calls and returns, you don't give a working snippet ... I can't really help you there. You're in your project, but remember that I'm not !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using bootstrap modals.  Once you've included the bootstrap JS code, you can call:

```
$('#editModal').modal('hide');
```

See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: Hi, I added that code but the backdrop is still there even though I submitted. Any idea how to destroy the backdrop completely?